# How do I call a function with a list of named arguments?

Tags: python

Consider the following function:

```
def test(first, second = None, third = None):
    print first
    print second
    print third

test('one', third = 'three')
```

I want to be able to call it with a list I build up with some logic (non-working pseudo code):

```
arguments = ['one']
arguments.append(third = 'three')

test(arguments)
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: dictionary is better option than list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
arguments.append(third = 'three')
```

is not possible. Use a dictionary:

```
args = {"third":"three"}
test("one", **args)
```

Output:

```
one
None
three
```

**Edit:** I don't see a point in using a separate structur for the positional arguments. As long as there is only one such argument, `*["one"]` is not shorter than `"one"`.

Comment: it's `*["one"]` :) And it's actually usefull: Thing of the case where the arguments are supplied by a dynamic source like a CLI or a web-service. You do not know in advance how many positional and named arguments will be passed :)

Comment: Sorry, typo. I don't doubt that this syntax is useful. But for the current question it feels like overkill.

Comment: Well, I would also argue that `**{"third": "three"}` is not shorted than `third='three'` (Completely useless comment :))

Answer (score 3):

Use a list for the positional arguments, and a dictionary for the named arguments. (c.f. [The Python Tutorial 4.7.4. Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments))

```
positionalArguments = ['one']
namedArguments = {
  'third': 'three'
}

test(*positionalArguments, **namedArguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot do

```
arguments.append(third = 'three')
```

This is not a valid python instruction. What you are looking for is a dictionary

```
arguments = {'first': 'one'}
arguments['third'] = 'three'
```

The good news is that in python, you are able to call a function by passing a list of positional arguments and/or a list of named arguments. You would use the magic [* and ** symbols](http://markmiyashita.com/blog/python-args-and-kwargs/)

- The * operator let you pass positional arguments as a list
- The ** operator let you pass named arguements as a dictionary

Following your example, you would do the following:

```
pargs = ['one']
kwargs = {'third': 'three'}
test(*pargs, **kwargs)
```